# Unicode encoding/decoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a string that looks like this.

```
st = '/M\xe4rzen'
```

I would like to covert this to unicode. How can I do this? I've tried:

```
st.decode('utf-8')
unicode(t, 'utf-8')
```

The original file is utf-8 encoded, but I can't seem to get the unicode representation of the string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your data is not UTF8 encoded; more likely it is using the Latin-1 encoding:

```
>>> print st.decode('latin1')
/Märzen
```

Calling `.decode()` is enough, no need to *also* call `unicode()`.