# Decode unicode string in python

Tags: python, unicode

I'd like to decode the following string:

t\u028c\u02c8m\u0251\u0279o\u028a\u032f

It should be the IPA of 'tomorrow' as given in a JSON string from http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getWordInfo&word=tomorrow

My understanding is that it should be something like:

```
x = 't\u028c\u02c8m\u0251\u0279o\u028a\u032f'
print x.decode()
```

I have tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278912/python-decode-unicode-string) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267019/double-decoding-unicode-in-python) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637419/unicode-encoding-decoding), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056863/decode-an-encoded-unicode-string-in-python) (and several other that more or less apply), and several permutations of its parts, but I can't get it to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `u` before your string (in Python 2.x, which you appear to be using) to indicate that this is a unicode string:

```
>>> x = u't\u028c\u02c8m\u0251\u0279o\u028a\u032f'  # note the u
>>> print x
tʌˈmɑɹoʊ̯
```

If you have already stored the string in a variable, you can use the following constructor to convert the string into unicode:

```
>>> s = 't\u028c\u02c8m\u0251\u0279o\u028a\u032f'  # your string has a unicode-escape encoding but is not unicode
>>> x = unicode(s, encoding='unicode-escape')
>>> print x
tʌˈmɑɹoʊ̯
>>> x
u't\u028c\u02c8m\u0251\u0279o\u028a\u032f'  # a unicode string
```

Comment: your edit was exactly what I was trying to figure out just now, thanks for the forethought.